c# .NET Mac ARM64 program won't launch browser for Microsoft Identity OAUTH login
I have been building a program that runs on Avalonia (Cross platform) and so far a single codebase has been perfect between Mac and windows clients.
I have developed a feature on windows that uses Microsoft Identity OAuth and the Graph API to send emails from the end users email when the program is required to.
this code works on windows:
public async Task<bool> auth()
    {
        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("APP_KEY") //redacted for privacy
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost") 
            .Build();

        AuthenticationResult authResult;
        try
        {
            // Get cached account if available
            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
            
            
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync();
            
            _token = authResult.AccessToken;
            cachedAccount = authResult.Account;
            return true;
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            // Fall back to interactive login using system browser
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                .WithSystemWebViewOptions(new SystemWebViewOptions
                {
                    OpenBrowserAsync = SystemWebViewOptions.OpenWithEdgeBrowserAsync
                })
                .ExecuteAsync();
            try
            {
                _token = authResult.AccessToken;
                cachedAccount = authResult.Account;
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

However when I run the application on Mac, it hangs on this line:
authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
            .WithSystemWebViewOptions(new SystemWebViewOptions
            {
                OpenBrowserAsync = SystemWebViewOptions.OpenWithEdgeBrowserAsync
            })
            .ExecuteAsync();

This program is still in development and is unsigned, is there a problem launching browser due to permissions? or do I need to adapt the code for Mac to make it launch the OAuth login?
